# Camera Failed Error on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.3-jelly-bean, camera

Getting error message  on Samsung Galaxy S3, running Android 4.3.  Have tried rebooting,  clearing Data, Cache and Force Stop with no success.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this a stock Android 4.3 installation or a custom ROM? Rooted or not? Have you tried the nuclear option or factory reset?

Comment: You need to elaborate on "Getting error message". What are you doing when you get that error message? When did it start happening? What camera app are you using?